# T-SQL UNION On 3 Tables?

Tags: t-sql, union

Is this possible?
Using SQL Server 2005.......

```
SELECT *
FROM Data0304 
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM Data0506
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM Data0708
```

Comment: Did you try running this already? Any issues with it? What didn't work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the columns are the same in all three tables, but you might want to use UNION ALL to ensure duplicates are included.

Comment: And should specify the column names rather than using `*`.

Answer (score 8):

When you say

> **columns are same**

that means,

> **number of columns and data types and
>   their lengths and their order**

should be same.

> **UNION**

will include duplicate records only once in the result and

> **UNION ALL**

will include all the duplicate records.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. The clarification about "columns are the same" was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

in order to include duplicate records you have to use UNION ALL instead of UNION

```
SELECT *
FROM Data0304 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Data0506
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Data0708
```