# How to join more than 2 tables to get union the result?

Tags: sql, join

[image: the Venn show what I want&what I get]

I have a SQL like this:

```
    SELECT 
           A.NAME,
           A.CODE,
           B.b_grade,C.c_grade 
      FROM A
     JOIN B ON B.NAME = A.NAME
     JOIN C ON C.NAME = A.NAME
```

I want to get the result like the Veen show. but the SQL's result give me another.

PS:the table B don’t have column “c_grade” ,so at the sql result ,for B ,the column “c_grade ” can be set zero

Comment: Which one of your tables A or B or C in this case ?

Comment: I have updarte the description

Comment: A Venn diagram does not depict the result of a join. It depicts the result of a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336091/t-sql-union-on-3-tables check this out.
Should help Ignore my previous answer

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your question is also unclear on whether you want the rows that are in all three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Below is all you need to do.

[Set Operators](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/set-operation-in-sql.php)

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.CODE, B.B_GRADE, NULL AS C_GRADE
  FROM A JOIN B ON B.NAME = A.NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT A.NAME, A.CODE, NULL AS B_GRADE, C.C_GRADE
  FROM A JOIN C ON C.NAME = A.NAME
```

Comment: This isn’t what I want, I will update my questions again

Comment: Edited @ZhengyiZhang

Comment: thanks for your answer. But,  I have more than 3 tables. Actually, I having 8 tables,If we defined  the A as MAIN table ,I will get 7 column from the aother 7 tables. so ,your plan is not Plain and simple. thanks again.

Comment: There is no plain and simple way to achieve your goal here. @ZhengyiZhang

Comment: @ZhengyiZhang . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you asked, which is specifically about three tables.  This appears to answer that question -- you should accept this or another answer that answers *the question you asked*.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question, with a clear explanation, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can left outer join, and then check whether any of the tables matched:

```
SELECT 
       A.NAME,
       A.CODE,
       B.*,C.*
  FROM A
 LEFT JOIN B ON B.NAME = A.NAME
 LEFT JOIN C ON C.NAME = A.NAME
 WHERE B.NAME != NULL OR C.NAME != NULL
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`  can get a result , but what I want is  only the shadowed side of the Venn. I give a Venn in the  description.

Comment: @ZhengyiZhang Your Venn shows the union between the intersections of A and B, and the intersection of A and C, correct? Then either the answer by ismetguzelgun or mine should be working. As to there being 8 tables: well some SQL statements just get big, that's just how it is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabA 
INNER JOIN tabB
      ON tabA.primaryKey=tabB.tabAId
INNER JOIN tabC
      ON tabA.primaryKey=tableC.tabAId
```

Comment: your sql  is equel to mine.     `INNER JOIN`  is equel to `JOIN`

Comment: This is exactly what the question asker did; `JOIN` by default is an inner join.